# GNU Radio | Grouping just 24 consecutive soft bits from a repeating tagged stream onto 3 bytes, starting from a specified tag

Tags: gnuradio

A `vector source` [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1] produces repeatedly a tagged stream with one tag, `my_tag` (offset: 2), in blue, I want to group 24 consecutive bits onto 3 bytes, starting from `my_tag` and send them to a file, `out.dat`.
`out.dat` would be then filled with consecutive 0x01's: 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 0x01 ...

[image]

I am adding a [flowgraph](https://pastebin.com/raw/GbKnu1jZ) (GR-v3.8) that does everything except the part I am looking for. How can I change this FG to achieve the goal?

[image]